# Expex glosses get broken when unicode-math is loaded in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode-math, linguistics, expex

I'm trying to typeset multiline numbered examples with John Frampton's    expex package (version 4.1). Since I'm using XeLaTeX (TeXLive 2012), I've picked    unicode-math to typeset maths. The following MWE illustrates the problem, which is that the first and second lines of the multiline example are no longer separated properly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{expex}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

\ex 
\begingl
\gla See on lühike tekst {eesti keeles}.//
\glb This is short text {in Estonian}//
\glft `This is a short text in Estonian.'//
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

The only warning I get is the innocuous *xparse/redefine-command* warning, and once I remove     unicode-math, the output looks as desired. What's going on here and is there a solution? I should probably add that the same behaviour is observed when I compile with LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `unicode-math` package defines a `\gla` command for a (quite rare) character.

You can do it with the following trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\usepackage{expex}
\let\expexgla\gla
\AtBeginDocument{\let\gla\expexgla}

\begin{document}

\ex
\begingl
\gla See on lühike tekst {eesti keeles}.//
\glb This is short text {in Estonian}//
\glft `This is a short text in Estonian.'//
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

The definitions of `unicode-math` happen at begin document, so you need to redefine `\gla` to the saved version after that.